# Open URL in browser even though my app registered an intent-filter for it

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

My app registers an intent filter for certain URLs because it can handle the data from those URLs.

However, inside the app I would like to provide a button to open such an URL in the browser. That is, open it in the default browser if one is set, otherwise provide a chooser - just like normal.

Now when my app is set as default for those URLs and I press the button, naturally I just get the same activity in my app again and again and again.

Any ideas?

Comment: u using sample like this? Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);

Comment: Interesting problem.  Is there any way you could reserve certain sub-folders to resolve to the app, and other sub-folders to resolve to the web?  Then you could modify your intent filter to only include sub-folders that should resolve to the app.

Comment: @DanielNugent It's not my website, I am using their API and they provide permalinks that I use for my intent-filter. I guess I could add a parameter (or a double-slash or something) as they ignore them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I ended up doing is:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("https://website.com/entries/" + entry_id));

// Check what is the default app to handle these entry URLs

ResolveInfo defaultResolution = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(i,
        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

// If this app is the default app for entry URLs, use the browser instead

if (defaultResolution.activityInfo.packageName.equals(getPackageName())) {

    Intent browseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://"));

    ResolveInfo browseResolution = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(browseIntent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    i.setComponent(new ComponentName(
            browseResolution.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
            browseResolution.activityInfo.name));

}

startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of two things:

1. Create an explicit Intent for the browser if you know that one (Chrome, for example) will be installed on the device
2. Create a chooser by using

   `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.com"));
   Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Title for chooser");
   startActivity(chooserIntent);`

You can read more about createChooser [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence))