# How do I bypass Android intent filter when my app is open and user has selected to "always" open domain in my app?

Tags: android, intentfilter

My app intercepts my entire website domain. However, I occasionally cannot support a particular page in app. When this happens, I want to redirect the user back to the browser. Unfortunately, if the users has selected "Always" to open my app with this domain (rather than selecting "Only Once"), I get stuck in a redirect loop.

Comment: AndreKR already answered a similar question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529027/open-url-in-browser-even-though-my-app-registered-an-intent-filter-for-it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529027/open-url-in-browser-even-though-my-app-registered-an-intent-filter-for-it)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new intent with your url
2. Create a second temporary intent with a generic http:// url
3. Get the default resolution for the temporary intent
4. Set the original intent to the default resolution
5. Start the original intent

   ```
       Intent intent = null;
       try {
           // #1
           intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
           intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
           // #2
           Intent tempIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://"));
           // #3
           var resolution = activity.PackageManager.ResolveActivity(tempIntent, Android.Content.PM.PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);
           // #4
           intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName(
               resolution.ActivityInfo.ApplicationInfo.PackageName,
               resolution.ActivityInfo.Name));
           // #5
           StartActivity(intent);
       }
       catch {
       }
   ```